# Custom fields in Contact US

Tags: magento-1.9, contact-us

I'm trying to add custom fields to default Contact Us form but they are not displaying at all. I have used this procedure:
1. Edit form.phtml (inside my theme) and I put this code after Telephone:

```
<li>
<label for="subject"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Subject') ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
<div class="input-box"><input name="subject" id="subject" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Subject') ?>" value="" class="required-entry input-text" type="text"/>
```

2.Create a custom transactional email template where I load Contact Form and then I insert 
Subject: {{var data.subject}}

3.Then in System > Configuration > General > Contacts I assign a Custom Contact Form template and Save.

Nothing happens, my contact form is still the same. Any hint?
Thanks

EDIT: Procedure described in this question is correct, I was changing wrong package file in app, so check allways with path hint if you are changing correct file.

Comment: I'm assuming your field appears on the frontend? if you add `{{var data}}` to your email template what do you get?

Comment: On frontend appears only standard fields as: Name, Email, Telephone and Comment. Even if I add {{var data.subject}} nothing happens, Subject field is not shown

Comment: make sure your editing correct file by path hint

Comment: can you edit your question with the full path of the file and all the contents

Comment: Meenakshi Sundaram R thank you a lot, I edited wrong form.phtml, after this I'm going in to the corner... Now works all, without problems.

Comment: bn302...please edit your question with answer and mark it as solved....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Procedure described in this question is correct, I was changing wrong package file in app, so check allways with path hint if you are changing correct file. 
So suggestion made by  [Meenakshi Sundaram R](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/2677/meenakshi-sundaram-r) is correct.